# Python socket.sendall() function

Tags: python, sockets

I'm reading *[Tutorial on Network Programming with Python](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyNet.pdf)*, and in this document the author is saying that "The function sendall() should be used only with blocking sockets."

But I do not see any such condition in the Python documentation, *[socket.sendall(string[, flags])](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall)*.

Is the author of PyNet right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When in doubt, [check the source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/socketmodule.c?view=markup#l2729).

`socket_sendall` clearly gives up once send() returns -1, which it will do (with errno of EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK) if you call it on a non-blocking socket without calling poll() or select().  (And the `internal_select` function skips calling poll()/select() when the socket is non-blocking.)

So I would say the PyNet author is correct.

Comment: doesn't that sounds like a mistake from the developer of that module not to have handled `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` ? these can hardly be considered exceptional conditions, imho.

Answer (score 6):

sendall() doesn't make sense on non-blocking socket. It has to block if it can't send all data at once, otherwise it wouldn't be called "sendall".